Similar triangles understanding
why does $AD:DB=AE:EC$ applies to figure $y$?
I understand that triangle $ABC$ is similar to triangle $ADE$.


$$DB:AD = AD:AD + AB:AD = 1 + AB:AD $$ and $$ EC:AE = AE:AE + AC:AE = 1+AC:AE $$

By alternate interior angles in parallel lines, we have that $\angle EDB = \angle BCE$, and $\angle DEC = \angle BCE$. Thus, by AA similiarity, $\triangle EAD \sim \triangle CAB$.

The answer by @Andy Liu is the best first answer. Here is a second answer.
Consider in the left diagram $AB$ and $AC$ as lines extending beyond their endpoints - just lines at some angle. Clearly the exact positions of parallel lines $DE$ and $BC$ is not important for the similarity you acknowledge on the left. But what happens beyond the vertex $A$, above it? The lines extend, and the $ED$ in the second picture is just another version of those parallel lines.
A different way to see this is to consider what happens if you rotate triangle $ADE$ by a half-turn in the left panel. The triangle follows the same lines and parallel lines. You already know the similarity exists. But it exists above. And the lengths separating the parallel lines were arbitrary. So it exists for all such triangles.

If you translate the line $DB$ along the line $DE$, the the point $A$ stays at the same height, and $\triangle EAA'\sim \triangle ECB'$, and so the figure is figure X.
